# Proof or disprove: if an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is not invertible, then for every $n \times n$ matrix $B$, $AB$ is not invertible.

Tags: matrices

> Proof or disprove: if an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is not invertible, then for every $n \times n$ matrix $B$, $AB$ is not invertible.

Having trouble with this proof. Don't know how to start or what to look for.

Comment: Depends on the tools you have. If you know a matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is non-zero, and that the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants, it's over. If you know that a matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if the linear transformation induced by $A$ is onto, then again it's over.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So what you're saying is if det(A) = 0, then the det(AB) has to be equal to 0 no matter what B is, making this statement true?

Comment: Yes. But the point is that these results (invertible iff det not $0$, det of $AB$ is det of $A$ times det of $B$) have to have been **already** proved in your course. Same with the other approach.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yea, we've covered determinants in class. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. If the two theorems I mentioned have been proved, you can certainly use them. I like the second approach I suggested better, since it is more conceptual.

Answer (score 1):

$$AB\;\;\text{invertible}\;\implies\;\exists\;P\;\;s.t.\;\; I=(AB)P=A(BP)\implies A\;\;\text{invertible. Contradiction}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of the concept of rank of a matrix, we can prove a slightly stronger statement: $$\text{rank}(AB) \leq \text{rank}(A)$$

If $\text{rank}(A) = p$, we then have $A = UV^T$, where $U,V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$. This gives us $AB = U (V^TB)$, which is of the form $UW^T$, where $U, W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$. Hence, $\text{rank}(AB) \leq p = \text{rank}(A)$.